# Bold/italics are broken on the full site (for some users)

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Bold and italics aren't working for Latin letters on the full site:

> [image: screen shot of full site with missing formatting]

In the screen shot above, the Japanese characters are bolded, but the Latin letters are not, [even though the author used bold for the entire last sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/revisions/56270/2).

On the mobile site, they appear properly:

> [image: screen shot of mobile site behaving properly]

The entire sentence is bolded as expected, including both Japanese characters and Latin letters.   Bold and italics also work fine on other SE sites, so as far as I can tell the problem is limited to Japanese.SE.

Both screen shots were taken using Firefox on Windows 7, although it's broken for me on Chrome on Windows 7 as well.

Could we please have this fixed so we can use bold and italics again?

Comment: Looks fine here -- what browser and operating system are you on?

Comment: Looks fine on Firefox 57 on Linux.

Comment: I haven't been able to do either italics or bold since I started here two weeks ago. Windows 10, Chrome browser.

Comment: I can confirm the bug with latest Firefox (58.0.1) and Chrome (64.0.3282.119) on Ubuntu, whereas Safari on iOS or Chrome on Android are fine.

Comment: Works here on Firefox 58.0.1 and Chrome 63.0.3239.132 / Windows 7.

Comment: @balpha Is someone going to have a look at this? The issue persists for me.

Comment: @Earthliŋ I'm looking at it now. It took me a while, but I have found *one* machine where I can reproduce this. It happens to be the only one with a high-definition screen, wonder if that's related.

Comment: @balpha Thank you! Actually — although I don't have a high-definition screen — I asked my OS (ubuntu) to scale menu/title bars and Firefox/Chrome might do something alike to a high-definition screen, i.e. recalculating numbers for pixels. (Note that bold/italics show fine for me on other SE sites, though. For example, https://academia.stackexchange.com/ seems to use the same font, but no problem with bold/italics there...)

Comment: Nevermind. I tried to use the default setting, restarted and bold/italics still don't show. May be a false trail...

Comment: @Earthliŋ Yeah, the high-def thing was a red herring. The actual difference between working or not working is whether the user has Open Sans installed locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed now. The reason why most people (including me) weren't able to reproduce this was that it only happened if you had the Open Sans font installed on your computer. The CSS is set up in a way that the font file is only downloaded if you *don't* have the font (in that case everything was fine), but the usage of your local font (for those users who have it) was set up incorrectly, causing the non-bold font file to be used even for bold text.